# Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

Today I switched my yarn version from 1.x to 3.x (latest) and I started having issues with the Typescript on my project.

I've seen many people having this same issue but unfortunately none of the solutions provided fixed it.

This is my current package.json version:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.8",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "dateformat": "5.0.3",
    "next": "12.2.4",
    "next-auth": "4.10.3",
    "next-cookie": "2.8.0",
    "next-seo": "5.5.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.16",
    "qs": "6.11.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "4.4.0",
    "sass": "1.54.4",
    "sharp": "0.30.7",
    "swr": "1.3.0",
    "tslib": "2.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "2.4.2",
    "@types/node": "18.7.14",
    "@types/qs": "6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Even adding `@types/react` to devDependencies I still get the error. I've also tried to restart the Vscode (and the computer), deleting `.yarn-lock`, deleting the directory `.yarn`  (I don't get node_modules anymore). No luck.

It also looks like Typescript is trying to find the types for every package I'm using but some of them don't have it, then through errors about them too.

It used to work well before this Yarn migration.

Does anyone know how to fix?  Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I found a fix for the issue. Following the step by step migration (https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#step-by-step) I was able to keep the node_modules folder on my project and that apparently fixed the issue with Typescript. I will keep this post open to someone who knows how to make Typescript works without having the node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should add `"type": "module` to package.json and `"moduleResolution": "node"` to tsconfig.json